# Flowplayer subtitle from javascript API is not working

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

I am using flowplayer v5.4.6. I am initializing my video player through flowplayer javascript API. Video play and works fine. I've provided subtitles through cuepoints as well as through subtitle entity. Problem is that flowplayer is not rendering the subtitles. Here is my code

```
function initVideoPlayer(pMedia, jsonData) {
    var title = "title 1";
    var subtitles = [];
    var entry = {
        title: title,
        startTime: seconds("00:00:01.000"),
        endTime: seconds("00:00:02.000"),
        text: "<p>The first subtitle </p><br/>"
    };
    subtitles.push(entry);
    var cue = {
        time: entry.startTime,
        subtitle: entry
    };
    jsonData.cuepoints.push(cue);
    jsonData.cuepoints.push({
        time: entry.endTime,
        subtitleEnd: title
    });

    title = "title 2";
    entry = {
        title: title,
        startTime: seconds("00:00:03.000"),
        endTime: seconds("00:00:05.000"),
        text: "<p>The second subtitle</p><br/>"
    };
    subtitles.push(entry);
    cue = {
        time: entry.startTime,
        subtitle: entry
    };
    jsonData.cuepoints.push(cue);
    jsonData.cuepoints.push({
        time: entry.endTime,
        subtitleEnd: title
    });

    $(pMedia).flowplayer({
        adaptiveRatio: true,
        playlist: [jsonData.sources],
        cuepoints: jsonData.cuepoints
    }).one('ready', function (ev, api) {
        api.resume();
    });
}
```

I checked flowplayer code. What I found that flowplayer check cuepoints in progress event and trigger cuepoint event from each cuepoint. But the event handler code is in different scope. In that handler it handles subtitle through cuepoint. This may be the reason for cuepoints not working from javascript API.

Anybody used subtitle from API or faced similar problem? Any kind of help will be much appreciated.